# Merge binary columns and keep the one

Tags: r

I have two binary columns:

```
col1 col2
0      1
0      0
1      0
1      1
```

I would like to merge this columns and if value 1 exist into one of in both columns I would like to have the 1 value. Example of output

```
merged_col
1
0
1
1
```

The general merged I tried is this:

```
merge(df$col1, df$col2, all = TRUE)
```

Any idea how can I handle the values?

Comment: Just use `rowSums(df)`

Comment: @akrun nice idea but for the option in which both columns have 1 I will take the result 2 and I lose the binary expression

Comment: THat is easy `as.integer(rowSums(df)>0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just treat them as logical values and use `or`...

```
df$col3 <- as.integer(df$col1|df$col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do what you need:

`df <- data.frame(col1 = c(0, 0, 1, 1), col2 = c(1, 0, 0, 1))
df$merge_col <- ifelse(df$col1 == 1 | df$col2 == 1, 1, 0)`